# R JGR: Non-existent directory specified in --libpath=

Tags: r

When invoking the JGR() function after installing JGR(), the output is:

```
Copy the following into WordPad and save as "jgrLaunch.bat"

set R_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-30~1.1
set R_LIBS=C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\library
set R_LIBS_USER=C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\library
jgr-1_62-x64.exe --rhome=C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-30~1.1 --libpath=C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\library

Starting JGR ...
```

A popup appears with the message "Non-existent directory specified in --libpath=."

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the space in the "Program Files" folder name. The workaround I used was to use the DOS path name in my jgrLaunch.bat:

```
set R_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-30~1.1
set R_LIBS=C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\library
set R_LIBS_USER=C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\library
jgr-1_62-x64.exe --rhome=C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-30~1.1 --libpath=C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-30~1.1\library
```

However the JGR() function overwrites this file every time it is invoked so this really needs to be fixed in the JGR source. Unfortunately the JGR bugzilla is not working at the moment...